# sed or awk, copy aside to create anchortext

Tags: sed, awk, anchor

How is it possible to transform this:

```
"dir1/dir2/../file1.ext"><
"dir1/dir2/../file2.ext"><
```

into this:

```
"dir1/dir2/../file.ext">file1.ext<
"dir1/dir2/../file.ext">file2.ext<
```

with `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
sed 's_/\([^/>]\+\)"><_/\1">\1<_g' file
```